# Build a docker file in one stage and use it in subsequent stage with out pushing it to docker hub in Gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Below is the sample stage template which i want to achieve,

```yaml
stages:
- build
- deploy

build:
- stage: build
  image:
- script:
  - docker build -t myimage .

deploy
- stage: deploy
  image: myimage
  script:
  - echo “it works”
```

so here am trying to use the image i built in the build stage. Please let me know if its possible.

Comment: You could make it possible (there are several possible solutions depending on your exact requirements) but the solution to put in place is going to be much more complex, resource intensive and hard to maintain than simply pushing the resulting image to a private registry.

Comment: Each GitLab project should have its own registry, can you use that instead of Docker Hub?

Comment: @StepTNT any idea how to retrieve the image pushed in it.. Or how to push to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login registry.gitlab.com -u <gitlab-uname> -p $ACCESS_TOKEN
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push registry.gitlab.com/<fill-with-you-registry-name>
```

Head over to you registry, it's listed in the repository side-bar in `CI/CD` section, to use that image while deploying-- `ssh` into the node from `gitlab-runner`, supply it with you account's `ACCESS_TOKEN` [required to push and pull images from docker registry], copy a script called `.gitlab-deploy.sh` onto this instance, which logs into docker registry using your `TOKEN` pulls the image, and runs it.

```
# deploy.sh
-------------
docker login registry.gitlab.com -u <gitlab-uname> -p $ACCESS_TOKEN

echo "[bash] pulling tile_server image from container registry"
docker pull registry.gitlab.com/<organization>/<repo>/<image>:latest
```